# Update session data not working - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, controller, disconnect

My problem is simple: I have in my table a field called `credit`.

I want to add 1 `credit` to a connected user, so I update the field `credit`. The update works well, but when I want to display the `credit`, the addition has not been done.

Example: the user `Joe` has logged with 2 `credit`. I add him 1 `credit`. It works in the database but not on the screen. The problem is solved if he disconnects and reconnects.

So, I'd like to know how can i update session data without disconnecting

Controller 'LoginArea'

```
$this->load->library('session');
$dataUser = array(
    'id' =>     $ligneBDD->{'id_user'},
    'name' =>   $ligneBDD->{'name'},
    'credit' => $ligneBDD->{'credit'}
);

// i store id, name and credit in my session
$this->session->set_userdata('data', $dataUser);
```

And this is my update :

```
$update= $this->User_model->update(array(
                                    'credit' => $userConnected['credit'] - 1
                                        ),  
                                        array(
                                        'id_user' => $userConnected['id'])
                                        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the session as a (**temporary**) "State" for a specific User.

If a login is performed (LoginArea), the current User-Data (and the credits) is fetched from your Database (DB **permanent** storage/state). This userData is then saved in the session.

But both, session and DB, are seperated and **not connected**.

So if you change the DB, this change is not reflected in the Session and vice-versa.

When you now update your DB, you **need to update the session too.**
So here you have two possible solutions:

1. The easiest solution would be to move the code for initializing
   the session in a method and call it again after updating the
   Database
2. or after updating the DB, load the current session, update only the `credit` attribute and save it again in the session (overwrite)

==> new (updated) data will be present in Session-UserData